# is she aggressive or just being a puppy?

Tags: dogs, biting

I recently bought a 6 week old German Shepherd (now she is 8 weeks old) and she won't stop biting. I know that she is a puppy, but she will bite my whole family (all except for me). How do I train her to stop biting? I've tried the whole loud ow, and that doesn't work. She just ignores it and bites you again. My family is freaking out about the biting so I was wondering if she's abnormally aggressive or just being a puppy.

*I know that you should not adopt a puppy before 8-12 weeks but there was a bad situation so she had to be taken away.*

Comment: BTW: a Shepherd is one who herds sheep: shep-herd. A Shepard is an astronaut :)

Answer (score 2):

When is the pup typically biting?  During playtime, during rest time, when you're giving a command?

**During play time:**
If your pup isn't responding to the high pitched yelp/ouch sound you'll have to teach her that biting makes the fun stop.  When she bites you (even if it seems like an accident), make a high pitched yelping sound, then immediately get up and walk away from her.  Ignore her for 3-5 minutes no matter what she does.  Then go back to playing.  If she bites again, rinse and repeat.  It will take consistency and patience but she will eventually learn that biting = no more fun.  This is (more or less) how other dogs teach puppies not to bite.

**When giving a command:**
Again, keep up the high pitched yelping in response.  Don't hide if it hurts.  Second, you should have a marker word for when your puppy has failed to properly respond to the command.  The word I use with my dogs is "whoops", but choose whatever you like (I don't recommend "no" for many reasons).  Use your marker word and try the command again.  Assuming she's biting your hands, try to keep your hands out of reach, even if slightly.  Rinse and repeat up to 3 times.  If she hasn't properly responded to the command on the 3rd round, try another command she's more reliable with and reward her if she exhibits the desired behavior.  If she gets it right on the 2nd or 3rd time (no biting + exhibiting the desired behavior) reward and praise like crazy!  Always end training on a high note, so that your pup associates training with fun and rewards and love, not only with all the times she missed the mark.

**During rest time**
If your pup is chewing on you when resting, this is likely a relic of being taken too early from the litter.  You should redirect her to a safe and appropriate chew toy.  Again, this takes consistency and patience but she will learn.

*You should get your pup into a puppy training class ASAP.  Being socialized around other puppies of similar age will help immensely with teaching things like bite inhibition and other basic behaviors.*